# Elastic search .json file upload Error "illegal_argument_exception"

Tags: elasticsearch, curl, post, illegalargumentexception

I am trying to upload a json file to an existing index in elastic search, the index mapping looks like this: [mapping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cJD4G.png).
and i am uploading a json file containing data in this form: [json file data sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AH9Vx.png).
I am getting the following "illegal_argument_exception" when uploading the file from cmd:

curl --insecure --cacert "path to cert" -u elastic: -X POST "https://localhost:9200/search-test2/_doc?pretty" -H "Content-Type:application/json" -d@C:/users/s/downloads/file-coderstool.json

"type" : "illegal_argument_exception",
"reason" : "mapper [ctRoot.score] cannot be changed from type [long] to [float]"

i have tried to post the data from the dev console in kibana to make sure the data is structured correctly and it worked fine.
i have tried creating a new index and changing the mapping to long or double or scaled float whit scalling factor 10 all tries ended with same error.
any suggestions why i am getting this error?

Comment: Did you try to create a new index with `ctRoot.score` field type `float` and upload the file? If so what was the error?

please share the output of `GET index_name` too.

Comment: which version of elasticsearch you using?

Comment: adding ctRoot to the mapping solved the problem thanks

Comment: now it is getting uploaded but as one document

Comment: Nice to hear it fixed. I'm sharing my comment as a reply

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new index with `ctRoot.score` field type `float`.

```
PUT index_name
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "ctRoot.score": {
        "type": "float"
      }
    }
  }
}
```